# PHP Calling a method in a calls and returning

Tags: php, function, methods, call

The link below is being used to call a function that is in the prescription.class.php file. This also uses smarty.

```
    <a id="ReIssueRx" href="{$CONTROLLER}prescription&ReIssueRx" class="css_button"><span>{xl t='Re-Issue'} ({xl t='Rx'})</span></a>
```

The function / method runs a sql script and finishes its job.

```
  function ReIssueRx(){

        sqlStatement( Do function to completion);

           return;
       }
```

The problem for me is that I want it to return to the original page where the link is located. I have tried Location:"backtourl.com" and refresh:"backtopage.com" but neither of these work. I have just tried at the end return 'linktopage.php'; and that just returns the words.

Is there a way to auto redirect out of a function back to a page or back to the calling page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` function to get the previous URL, store it in a variable and after your code execution is done you can use `header('location')` to return to the calling page.

like this:

```
$prev_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

function ReIssueRx(){

    sqlStatement( Do function to completion);

       header('location:' . $prev_page);
   }
```

Goodluck!